# Not overwriting elements in arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writing code for a program we are supposed to make in my computer science course I am taking, where we are learning C++. In this program, I'm trying to get a user to enter flavours of popcorn they may like, but without exceeding 10 (or 9) characters. When I tried including flavours with > 10 chars, the program would not result in an error or work properly, but would just store the chars exceeding 10 into the next element in the array. How can I stop the program from doing this?

```
#define POP_COUNT 5
#define POP_SIZE 10 

int main() {
    char popcorn[POP_COUNT][POP_SIZE];
    fputs("Enter your 5 favourite popcorn flavours: \n", stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < POP_COUNT; i++) {
        fgets(popcorn[i], POP_SIZE, stdin);
        popcorn[i][POP_SIZE - 1] = 0;
    }
    cout << popcorn[0] << endl;
    cout << popcorn[1] << endl;
    fputs("Your favourite flavours are: \n", stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < POP_COUNT; i++) {
        fputs(popcorn[i], stdout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to C++. The first stop on your tour is to learn about the [Standard Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) and containers like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) in particular as these are a lot easier to work with than C-style fixed-length arrays. You'll also want to declare things like `const size_t POP_COUNT = 5` instead of using C-style `#define` macros. C++ constants can be type-checked, macros can't.

Comment: There's a bizarre mix of C and C++ in your code. C++ programmers rarely use `fputs` and `fgets`.

Comment: If you used `std::string` instead of a fixed size character array then there would be no need for a limit at all. The code would be simpler and more robust. I realise you probably can't control what you are being taught but you're learning C++ the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue arises from the normal behavior of `fgets()`.  It will not read more characters than a buffer of the size you specify can accommodate, including space for a terminator.  Whatever it does not read on a given call remains waiting in the stream, and will be read on the next call.

To address this, you must first *detect* it.  You can do that by checking whether a newline was stored in the destination buffer.  If so, then you're good, but if not, then only a partial line has been read.  Note, too, that you do not need to manually insert a terminator -- `fgets()` will always include a terminator on success.

If you just want to discard any extra characters, then in the second case you must do exactly that -- read and ignore additional characters until either you have read a newline, or you reach the end of the file.